# How to make functions to repeat with different parameters in python?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, repeat

I'd like to make this process simple.

```
df_2001 = pop_grid_df_2020[["ISOCODE","geometry","CellXCoord","CellYCoord","count"]]
df_2001 = df_2001.assign(Year = 2001)
df_2001["min"] = np.nan

df_2002 = pop_grid_df_2020[["ISOCODE","geometry","CellXCoord","CellYCoord","count"]]
df_2002 = df_2002.assign(Year = 2002)
df_2002["min"] = np.nan

df_2003 = pop_grid_df_2020[["ISOCODE","geometry","CellXCoord","CellYCoord","count"]]
df_2003 = df_2003.assign(Year = 2003)
df_2003["min"] = np.nan
```

I need to do this process for multiple years.

```
list = [2001,2002,2003,2004,2006,2007,2008,2009,2011,2012,2013,2014,2016,2017,2018,2019]
```

And I made code like this.

```
list = [2001,2002,2003,2004,2006,2007,2008,2009,2011,2012,2013,2014,2016,2017,2018,2019]

def copy(list):
    for i in list
        df_i = pop_grid_df_2020[["ISOCODE","geometry","CellXCoord","CellYCoord","count"]]
        df_i = df.assign(Year = i)
        df_i = df["min"] = np.nan
        return df_i
    
copy(2001) = df_i
```

So please let me know the solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add what specific errors or bugs you are seeing when you run this? it looks like you're missing a semicolon in the for loop, add one to the end: `for i in list:`. Also it is generally a bad idea to use a python keyword as a variable name, consider renaming list` to something like `year_list`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
year_list = [2001,2002,2003,2004,2006,2007,2008,2009,2011,2012,2013,2014,2016,2017,2018,2019]

def copy(year_list):
    dfs = {}
    for i in year_list:
        df_i = pop_grid_df_2020[["ISOCODE","geometry","CellXCoord","CellYCoord","count"]]
        df_i = df.assign(Year = i)
        df_i = df["min"] = np.nan
        dfs[i] = df_i
    return dfs
```

Now your dictionary dfs will have all the datasets for the respective years. Please make sure not to use keywords(list is a keyword) for variables. Refer to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for best practices and guidelines on python coding